# Color Calendar Entry SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I work on SharePoint 2013.
I have a list that displayed as a calendar.
In specific conditions, I want to color an entry in the calendar.
How can I color the entry?
I tried to insert a Script Editor (via web parts) but it didn't work.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
                var overrideCtx = {};
                overrideCtx.Templates = {};
                overrideCtx.Templates.OnPostRender = Color;
                SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function Color(inCtx) {

                for (var i = 0; i < inCtx.ListData.Rows.length; ++i) {

                                var listItem = inCtx.ListData.Row[i];
                                var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(inCtx, listItem);
                                var row = document.getElementId(iid);
                                //if (listItem....)
                                row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)"; //red
                                row.style.color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)"; //red
                }

}


</script>
```

Comment: What are your conditions?

Comment: Value of one of the fields in the listItem.
But before that - I don't know how to color the entry

Comment: I see your title you want this for a calendar or is it for list view?  If it is for a calendar view you could do overlays and there are ways to do this for a list view.  I am just unsure which you need..

Comment: It is a list, but displayed as a calendar..